# ondragend event in Child Component calls Parent Component method

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dom

I'm trying to have a list of child ListItem components in my parent DragAndDrop component that are draggable but when dropped or stopped dragging it should call a method in my parent DragAndDrop component so I can run an algorithm to calculate values between all my child ListItem components.

I want to be able to drop any ListItem component visually in-place but also have it calculate new prop values.

***My current problem is I can't have a child component's ondragend event trigger a method in the parent.***

I've tried creating a method and passing it in through the props but it is not calling as expected.

This is all in codepen which is linked below and here is my code.

```
class ListItem extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

    render(){
       console.log('ListItem');
      return(    
        <li draggable="true" 
           ondragend={ (e) => this.props.onDragEnd(e) }
          className="item" >
        {this.props.data}
      </li>
       );
    }
}

class DragAndDrop extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: this.constructExample()
    };
  }


  onDragEndEvent = (e) => { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
    console.log('on drag end');
    console.log(data);
    //e.target.parentNode.insertBefore();
   }


  constructExample = () => {
   return(['A', 'B', 'C'].map( (i,x) => <ListItem key="i" data={x} onDragEnd={this.onDragEndEvent}/>));
  }

  onDragEvent = (e) => { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    this.dragged = e.currentTarget; 
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.dragged);

  }


  render() {
    console.log('DragAndDrop');
    return (
      <div>
        <h3 id="title">Drag and Drop Demo</h3> 
        <div className="drop-zone">
          <ul className="list"> 
            {this.state.items}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


//needed for display
ReactDOM.render( <DragAndDrop />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem here is that I had `ondrag` and `ondragend` in React they need to be `OnDrag` and `OnDragEnd`

I'm assuming it has to be because React is JSX and not HTML so it didn't recognize them correctly.